# Is there a way to retrieve Mobile Connect message content via API?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, mobile, mobileconnect

I created a SMS message in MobileConnect and I want to be able to retrieve this message object (content, short code, etc.) via the REST API but I can't find the appropriate endpoint when looking through the reference document (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/routes.html)

Is this not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. However, I'd try storing your message in a Content Area and using the `ContentArea()` [AMPscript function](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/content/ContentArea.html) in your mobile message. You can then use the API to [retrieve the Content Area](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/content-areas/content-area-retrieve.html).